# Relationship between the norm of a function and a linear operator

Tags: general-topology, normed-spaces

**Question:**

Let $ C[0,1] $ be the space of continuous functions $f: [0,1] \to \Bbb{R}$, with the norm $ \|f\| = \max\{|f(x)| : x \in [0,1]\} $. Consider the map $ T: C[0,1] \to \Bbb{R} $ given by $ T(f) = \int_0^1f(x)\,dx $. What is $\|T\|$?

**My Troubles:**

The problem clearly suggests that there is a connection between the norm of $f$ and the norm of $T$. My best guess is that $\|T\| = | \int_0^1f(x)\,dx|$. This satisfies the required conditions of a norm. I do not see why this must be the case though, since there are many norms for a given normed space.

Comment: Do you think there is a relation between the function values anywhere on f(x)and the norm of f, $||$f$||$. Should be a certain kind of inequality which should let you determine a similar relationship between $||$ T $||$ and $||$ f $||$

Comment: Which norm are you using on the space of maps from $C[0,1]\to\mathbb{R}$?

Comment: that is what I'm trying to find out @helloworld112358

Comment: @HumbleStudent the norm of $f $ is defined by it's functional values but I don't see how that helps

Comment: look at the answer below.. I think @Martin solved it

Answer (score 2):

The equality in your guess makes no sense: what is $f$?

You have, by definition, the usual norm on the dual
$$\tag{1}
\|T\|=\sup\{|Tf|:\ \|f\|=1\}.
$$
Also, for any $f$ with $\|f\|=1$,
$$
|Tf|=\left|\int_0^1 f\,\right|\leq\int_0^1|f|\leq\int_0^11=1.
$$
The above shows that $\|T\|\leq1$. But if we take the function $g(x)=1$, $x\in[0,1]$, then $Tg=1$. It follows that the sup in $(1)$ is achieved, and so $\|T\|=1$.